# Can you have gitolite repositories with spaces in the names?

Tags: gitolite

I want to have a SparkleShare repository that has spaces in the names, but it seems that gitolite doesn't like my config file to have spaces in the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitolite (v2 [or v3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html)) doesn't seem to support repo names with spaces in it.

If you look at [`Store.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm#L151):

```perl
# normal repos
my @repos = grep { $_ =~ $REPONAME_PATT and not /^@/ } sort keys %repos;
```

With [Rc.pm](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L43)

```perl
$REPONAME_PATT = qr(^\@?[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z._\@/+-]*$);
```

So no space in that pattern, when [adding or removing repos in Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/repos.html).

Comment: I wonder if changing that regex is all that would need to be done, or if that would break things...

Comment: @BryanAgee It's possible, but I haven't tested it.